# Can't get google firebase to presist data and initializeAuth is not working due to missing module... react-native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I have a react native application and I am trying to integrate firebase into the react native application. I build the entire signup screen and now I am trying to add the authentication portion.

I have the following error when I run my application:

```
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Your JavaScript code tried to access a native module that doesn't exist. 

If you're trying to use a module that is not supported in Expo Go, you need to create a development build of your app. See https://docs.expo.dev/development/introduction/ for more info., js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

Right now I have installed `npm install --save firebase @react-native-firebase/auth`

I have everything regarding the firebase setup in the firebase file:

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
  getReactNativePersistence,
  initializeAuth,
} from "@react-native-firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'

import Authorize from '../../Authorize'

const firebaseConfigProduction = {
  apiKey: Authorize.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: Authorize.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: Authorize.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: Authorize.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: Authorize.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: Authorize.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: Authorize.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

let firebaseApp;

if (!getApps().length) {
  firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfigProduction)
} else {
  firebaseApp = getApp()
}

const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp)

const auth = initializeAuth(firebaseApp, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage)
})

export { db, auth }
```

I am trying to integrate it into my signup screen:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions, Image, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { GeneralContext } from '../../../../context/GeneralContext';
import { Feather } from 'react-native-vector-icons'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

import { signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth'
import { auth, db } from '../../../../api/firebase'

const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width

const SignupPageScreen = () => {
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()
  const auth = getAuth()
  const navigation = useNavigation()

  const { screenType } = useContext(GeneralContext)

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  const signInUserUsingPopup = () => {
    
  }

  return (
    ...
  )
}

...

export default SignupPageScreen
```